# Calculating nth element of two sequences dependent on each other

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to calculate any element of a given sequence:
$$
a_n = a_{n-1}+b_{n-2}-1
$$
Where $b$ is another sequence:
$$
b_n = 2\cdot a_n+b_{n-2}+4
$$
And $a_0$, $a_1$, $b_0$, $b_1$ is given. Is there any other way than just mechanically do the calculations until I get to $n=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve for $b_{n-2}$ in the first equation to get

$$b_{n-2}=a_n-a_{n-1}+1$$

Reindex and substitute $b_n$ and $b_{n-2}$ into the second equation to get

$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}+1=2a_n+a_n-a_{n-1}+1+4$$

Solve for $a_{n+2}$ to get

$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+3a_n-a_{n-1}+4$$

Reindex to get

$$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}+4$$

To use this, we need $a_0$, $a_1$, and $a_2=a_1+b_0-1$.

Comment: [+1] Your deduction is exact, but the OP should check his/her equations because the third order recurrence you found for $a_n$ has not a simple solution : $a_n \approx 2+a(-1.4812)^n+(0.31111)^n+(2.1701)^n$....